# What is the meaning of rotation of a matrix by complex exponential?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, markov-chains, markov-process

I am reading the following theorem:[image]

I dont understand what the $4^{th}$ and $5^{th}$ points are telling me?
What is the meaning of the phrase "The spectrum of $A$ is invariant under rotation by $\exp{(i 2 \pi/P)}$"?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the intended point is that the spectrum is invariant under **multiplication** by $\exp(i 2 \pi/p)$, which is to say that it is invariant under rotation **by an angle of** $2 \pi/p$.

In other words, if $\lambda \in \Bbb C$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then so is $\exp(i 2 \pi /p)\lambda$.

I think that writing "rotation by $\exp(i 2\pi/p)$" was an error by the author.

Comment: What do we mean by rotation of $A$ by $\exp{(i2\pi/P)}$? Do we have to multiply $A$ by $\exp{(i2\pi/P)}$ in order to rotate $A$?

Comment: @SHASHANKRANJAN The text you cited says nothing about rotating $A$; it talks about rotating **the spectrum of** $A$. Also, as I explained in my answer, I think that writing "rotation by $\exp(i 2\pi/p)$" is a mistake.

Comment: $\sigma (A)$ is invariant under rotation by an angle  of $2\pi /p$. @SHASHANKRANJAN

Comment: @geetha290krm ; By $\sigma(A)$ do you mean the singular values of $A$?

Comment: @SHASHANKRANJAN $\sigma(A)$ is the spectrum of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

4. says that if $\lambda$ is an eigen value then so is $e^{i2\pi /p} \lambda$. Since $1$ is an eigen value of any row-stochastic matrix $A$ it follows that  when you multiply $1$ by any power of $e^{i2\pi /p}$ you get an eigen value of $A$.

Comment: What do we mean by rotation of $A$ by $\exp{(i2\pi/P)}$? Do we have to multiply $A$ by $\exp{(i2\pi/P)}$ in order to rotate $A$?

Comment: @geetha You don't necessarily get **all** eigenvalues in that fashion. For example, consider 
$$
A = \frac 13\pmatrix{0&0&2&1\\0&0&1&2\\2&1&0&0\\1&2&0&0},
$$
a doubly stochastic matrix with period $2$. Its eigenvalues are $\pm 1, \pm 1/3$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann You are right. I have edited my answer.